# Crypted file is not working

Tags: c#, cryptography

I started to learn about cryptography and I wanted to make my own file crypter.
After you run the program you must select file to encrypt and then stub. For now it is now encrypting but it is binding two files. After selecting this two files it will create file first.exe. Splitter string is for program to know where stub code ends and when  original file code starts. It is made like this

- stub
- splitter (some string)
- original file

When you run first.exe then it will create file cos.exe which should be the original file. But when i run it, it doesnt work. It shows "This app is not going to work on your computer" and it says that i need to find version for my OS. 
Here is the code for crypter:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        string stubpath, filepath;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                filepath = openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory + openFileDialog1.FileName;
            }



            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                stubpath = openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory + openFileDialog1.FileName;
            }
            byte[] originalfile = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
            byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("password");
            byte[] originalstubfile = File.ReadAllBytes(stubpath);
            byte[] arr1 = Combine(array, originalfile);
            ByteArrayToFile("first.exe", Combine(originalstubfile,arr1));

        }
        public bool ByteArrayToFile(string fileName, byte[] byteArray)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    fs.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        public static byte[] Combine(byte[] first, byte[] second)
        {
            byte[] ret = new byte[first.Length + second.Length];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(first, 0, ret, 0, first.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(second, 0, ret, first.Length, second.Length);
            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code for stub:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string exePath = Application.ExecutablePath;
            byte[] originalfile = File.ReadAllBytes(exePath);
            var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(originalfile);
            string[] tokens = str.Split(new[] { "password" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            //0 stub
            //1 original file
            byte[] toBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tokens[1]);
            File.WriteAllBytes(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+ "cos.exe", toBytes);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

[Here is the error(Polish Language)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEmuW.png)

Also I found that when I delete splitter string and I dont use stub but I use 2 files like ex. putty.exe then it works, so I think that there is a problem in the stub.

Comment: Don't use `Encoding.Default`.  Instead, use UTF8.

Comment: Also show us the [real error message](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/); don't try to paraphrase it.

Comment: I can give you printscreen but in Polish language

Comment: screenshot added

Comment: As an FYI: you could use `File.WriteAllBytes` instead of manually write the bytes to the created file. However, by reading only the data of the file you are not reading all the information that the OS keeps

Comment: Yes, but when I write simple program File.Readallbytes(dir) and then FIle.writeallbytes(dir,byte array) then File works